# Exception with duplicate label when transform data from Numeric to Nominal via python-weka-wrapper v0.3.10

Tags: python, weka

There's a data pre-processing problem with using the python-weka-wrapper v0.3.10 that I'd confusing for a couple of days.

I'm using the **create_instances_from_matrices()** to generate my dataset from ndarray to instance, which is numeric type.

And then save the dataset into an arff file(*numeric_data.arff*) via

```
Saver(classname="weka.core.converters.ArffSaver")
```

Then tried to transform my dataset to nominal type with

```
Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal", options=["-R", "first-last"])
```

The exception message output like:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A
>   nominal attribute (x2) cannot have duplicate labels (1).

However, with the same dataset(*numeric_data.arff*) I generated, it can be transform to nominal type via Weka GUI Explorer v3.8.1 successfully.

I'll be appreciated with any idea can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you have small values (< 10^6), which Weka all turns to 0.0 when saving (Weka only outputs 6 digits after the decimal point by default). If you apply your filter to the dataset before you save it, it should work.

Alternatively, you can tell the `ArffSaver` how many decimals you would like to use when saving the file (`-decimal` option). See also the Javadoc of the [ArffSaver](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/ArffSaver.html) class.

Comment: I'd tried but still failed without saving to an arff file. And also, those value of duplicate labels are all 1 (integer), not small values.

Comment: The python-weka-wrapper has a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-weka-wrapper) that you could post your script and dataset for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

(excerpt from [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-weka-wrapper/VjFBsO6xtzA) on the mailing list, to answer this question properly)

The *NumericToNominal* filter is a very dumb filter. Its sole purpose was to have an easy way of converting numeric values that are supposed to be categorical ones (e.g., 1.0, 2.0 into labels 1 and 2). When turning numbers into labels, it cuts the decimals off after 6 decimals. However, it didn't check whether this could lead to generating duplicate labels. E.g., 2.00000001 and 2.0 will both generate 2 (or 2.0) as label.

You can use the *NumericCleaner* filter to remove these trailing decimals, e.g.:

```
# round to specified number of decimals
decimals = 3
cleaner = Filter(classname="weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericCleaner", options=["-R", "first-last", "-decimals", str(decimals)])
cleaner.inputformat(data)
data = cleaner.filter(data)
```